# Is there a need to have both private IP and private DNS when EC2 instance is launched. Isn't one of them sufficient?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ip

I am trying to understand the difference between a private IP and a private DNS. From what I can tell either can be used to SSH into the instance, then what is the use case/advantage of having both assigned when an EC2 is spun up. Having either one of them wasn't sufficient? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> private IP and a private DNS

Private means not public, so it cannot be used publicly.

> either can be used to SSH into the instance

None of them can be used for that. Because you cannot connect to private instance via SSH.

IP can be changed, DNS name can be preserved. i.e. One DNS name can correspond to many IPs in different moments. Users of this service don't need to be updated every time IP is changed, because they use its DNS name that is static.

Comment: By ssh using private IP or private DNS I meant from within my private network. Why is there a need to have both provisioned when EC2 is spun up?

Comment: It’s not possible to participate in the network communication without IP (even NAT one). I described why DNS is useful.